# Asp.net MVC Core giving null checkbox data instead of all selected checkboxes on HTTPPost

Tags: asp.net-core

I am trying to bind list of checkboxes.On Post Model showng the value of `Job_Type` as 0  .It should return all selected checkboxes.Which in my case not doing so .After hours of searching I havn't found any solution.

This is the relevent part of code in my view

```
 <div class="form-group">
                    @foreach (var item in Model.Job_Type)
                    {
                        <input name="Job_Type" value="@item.valID" type="checkbox" checked="@item.IsChecked"/>
                        @item.text <br/>
                    }

                </div>
```

My Controller:

```
  // GET: Jobs/Create
        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            NewJob newJob = new NewJob();
            List<CheckBoxModel> chkVisatype = new List<CheckBoxModel>()
            {
                new CheckBoxModel {valID=1, text="ASp",IsChecked=true },
                new CheckBoxModel {valID=1,text="ss",IsChecked=true },
                new CheckBoxModel {valID=1,text="aa",IsChecked=true },
                new CheckBoxModel {valID=1,text="dd",IsChecked=true },
            };
            List<CheckBoxModel> chkJobtype = new List<CheckBoxModel>()
            {
                new CheckBoxModel {valID=1,text="ASp",IsChecked=true },
                new CheckBoxModel {valID=1,text="tt",IsChecked=true },
                new CheckBoxModel {valID=1,text="ss",IsChecked=true },
                new CheckBoxModel {valID=1,text="aa",IsChecked=true },
            };
            newJob.Job_Type = chkJobtype;
            newJob.Visa_Type = chkVisatype;
            return View(newJob);
        }

        // POST: Jobs/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("JobID,Job_Title,AddedDate,Primary_Technology,MPTJob_Length,MPTJobLengthSelection,SPTJob_Length,SPTJobLengthSelection,Job_Length,JobLengthSelection,Secondary_Technology,Description,PossibiltyForExtenshion,Email,CC_Email,URL,City,State,Country,ZipCode,Employment_Type,Job_Type,Compensation,JobExperienceLevel,Visa_Type")] NewJob newJob)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                newJob.AddedDate = DateTime.Now;
                _context.Add(newJob);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View(newJob);
        }
```

My Model:

```
 public class CheckBoxModel
    {
        [Key]
        public int valID { get; set; }
        public string text { get; set; }
        public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
    }
 public class NewJob
    {

public List<CheckBoxModel> Job_Type { get; set; }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you check the request in browser Network tab, you would find only `valID` of checked options are sent via form data, like below. So `Job_Type` property is not successfully bound, which cause the issue.

[image]

If possible, you can dynamically generate expected data based on checked options, and then submit the data using jQuery AJAX etc.

*In View page*

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Job_Type)
{
    <input name="Job_Type" value="@item.valID" type="checkbox" checked="@item.IsChecked" />
    <span>@item.text</span>
    <br />
}
```

*Make ajax request*

```
function myCreateFunc() {

    var job_title = $('input[name="Job_Title"]').val();

    var job_type = [];


    $('input[name="Job_Type"]:checked').each(function (i,el) {

        job_type.push({ "valID": $(el).val(), "text": $(el).next("span").text(), "IsChecked": true });    
    });

    var job_data = { "Job_Title": job_title, "Job_Type": job_type };

    $.ajax({
            url: "/Home/Create",
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify(job_data),
            success: function (response) {
                //code logic here
            }
        });
}
```

*In controller action (with [FromBody] attribute)*

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Create([FromBody][Bind("JobID, Job_Title, Job_Type")]NewJob newJob) //in my testing sample, only define JobID, Job_Title, Job_Type properties
```

*Test Result*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well I tired this and it works for me.

All we need to understand how checkboxes post their data. if they have a name attribute, when checked, they post name=value.If you want to get  complete list posted back it would be:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Job_Type.Count(); i++)
{
    <input hidden asp-for="Job_Type[i].valID" />
    <input hidden asp-for="Job_Type[i].text" />
    <input asp-for="Job_Type[i].IsChecked" type="checkbox" />
    @Model.Job_Type[i].text<br />
}
```